# How to get side element in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm working with XSL 1.0 and I need an expression like "match all `<a>` elements that have `<b>` just at their right, but nothing among them", something like that:

```
<a/>text<b/> --> WRONG
<a/><b/>text --> RIGHT
```

I hope you can help me again. Thank you so match!

Comment: An [mcve] showing input, attempted XSLT and expected output would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> match all `<a>` elements that have `<b>` just at their right, but nothing among them

I believe that translates to *`a` elements whose immediately following sibling node is a `b` element* - so I guess you want:

```
match="a[following-sibling::node()[1][self::b]]"
```